# AngularJS $http - how to add query params to POST request

Tags: php, angularjs, post

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to POST data to call.php page from AngularJS page. My code for that is:

```
var request=$http({
                    url: "call.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { uid: uname,upass: upass }
                });
```

But on call.php page it says undefined `index:uid`.I want this uid and pass on call.php page and according to that I will search database row.
Please help me, Where I am wrong?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle for your snippet

Comment: Don't think you need the method part. Your api should know when it hits. I could be wrong though. I never put it in for my get requests.

Comment: URL for fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/ak21/3zujtuop/1/

Comment: Don't Use JQuery inside of angular controller, use `$scope` instead of JQuery selectors

Comment: I have tried using $scope.uname to get the value but its not working

Comment: @Ankit21ks your jsfiddle file not working,fix it's errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) use `$http.post('/target/url', optionalDataInRequestBody, params: { param1: 'value1', param:2: 'value2'})`, post sends data as request body but it looks like you want to acces them as query params.